# Execute a method after jQuery each iteration which is calling asynchronous request

Tags: jquery, promise

I have a jQuery each method. On every iteration it is making asynchronous call. I want to execute a method only after getting responses for all the request. In angular there is promise array for this. Is here something similar in jQuery or any other simpler solution?

Following is my code.

```
jQuery.each(self.object.feeds, function(pk, feed) {
  self.object.polling(feed);
});
```

In the above method each iteration is calling ***self.object.polling(feed)*** which is making asynchronous call to server.Appreciate any help/suggestion

Comment: we have promises in jquery as well https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Does your method `self.object.polling` return a Promise?

Comment: @Satpal No. It just has success method which calls some other method

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes there is promise in jQuery as well but as I said on each iteration there is asynchronous call. Is there any way where I can store promises for each iteration and then execute a function after all the iterations are complete?

Comment: store promises in an array. use `$.when` to wait for them all. `$.when` is equivalent to `Promise.all` - but (as is usually the case with jquery) subtly different.

Comment: note, the fact that you are using an ancient version of jquery would be useful in the question. You state in a comment in the deleted answer `polling is returning promise` - but here you state the polling does not return a promise.